# C++ queue - simple example

Tags: c++, queue

I can't find simple example how to use queues in C++ for pointers to some myclass objects. I have code like this:

```
class myclass{
  string s;
};

myclass *p = new myclass();

my_queue.push(p);

//something....

p = my_queue.front();
my_queue.pop();

std::cout << p->s;
```

What should be **declaration of my_queue**? Should I use queue or another data structure?

I need c++ just for small program, **thanks** for answers.

Comment: is this using your own queue implementation, or something else?

Comment: i am using std::queue on linux, but i am lookig for any possible solution...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Simply declare it as below if you want to us the STL queue container.

```
std::queue<myclass*> my_queue;
```

Comment: @RedX: This one got my vote because it's more complete and mentioned STL.

Answer (score 11):

`std::queue<myclass*> my_queue;` will do the job.

See [here](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/container/queue/start) for more information on this container.

Answer (score 10):

`std::queue<myclass*>` that's it